# Not detecting messages sent by a device

Tags: azure-iot-hub

We have an Azure IoT hub with a device configured to send messages to the Hub. We have the device defined and it's sending messages. However, Azure is not detecting any messages being sent by the device. The last activity date for the device is blank. Is there anyway to determine if our hub is receiving messages but doesn't recognize the device? Or is there anything else we can do to determine if the fault is with our IoT setup or device setup?

I would think there is a way to do this because our hub is telling us that 27 messages have been received, but the device in question doesn't show any activity. So I'm hoping I can determine the Id of the device sending these messages.

Comment: use IoTHub/Metrics portal to see 'Messages delivered to the built-in endpoint (messages/events)', also the tiny tool Device Explorer can be useful for consuming the D2C messages.

Comment: For testing an Azure IoT Hub from the device-facing side, the MQTTBox client (http://workswithweb.com/mqttbox.html) can be useful or for a mqtt device simulation can be used the tiny Azure IoT Hub tester - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester

Comment: What protocol and maybe SDK are you using to send those messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Azure IoT Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-toolkit) extension for Visual Studio Code to monitor the messages sent to Azure IoT Hub. It will also show the id of the device sending these messages.

[image: Monitor D2C messages]